# How to install GTK3 and Firefox on Amazon Linux (EC2) instance?

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami, amazon-linux

I'm trying to install the firefox on amazon linux (ec2) instance.. but this seems very difficult as gtk3 cannot be installed directly via yum.

I've seen some articles [here](https://joekiller.com/2012/06/03/install-firefox-on-amazon-linux-x86_64-compiling-gtk/#comment-6035). but not very helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Hey @Ranjith's, any luck with this? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: Not much luck on this.. using chrome instead firefox.

Comment: Yeah, me neither. Just for future reference, in case someone is interested, the only way I made it work was by using the ubuntu image instead of linux ami and installing firefox via apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

For Amazon Linux 2023, the steps I followed are below. Make sure to update the version to the latest (or whatever you need). You can find the current version number at https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/releases/ and all the available versions at https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/

```
# Depending on your application, you may need Development Tools
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"

sudo yum install dbus-glib.x86_64
cd /tmp
# update this URL
wget https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/118.0.2/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-118.0.2.tar.bz2
cd /opt
# update this filename
sudo tar -xf /tmp/firefox-118.0.2.tar.bz2   
sudo ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering its an **amazon-linux-2** (you can check with--> cat /etc/os-release)

Install Dependencies for Firefox->

1. sudo yum install -y gtk3
2. sudo yum install -y libdbusmenu
3. sudo yum install -y libdbusmenu-jsonloader

Installing FireFox:

1. cd /opt
2. sudo wget
   https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/93.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-93.0.tar.bz2
3. sudo tar xfj firefox-93.0.tar.bz2
4. firefox --version
5. sudo ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox